# Issue while validating complex data(dulpicate value also displaying)

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a list of objects in that same record presented two times. But when I apply distinct it is not removing as it is case sensitive.

I tried in three ways:

1. list data converted in to anonymous type
2. implemented I Equality CompareEquals in class by overriding equals and hash code
3. separate class to implement I compareequals interface.

---

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        List<Employee> lstEmployee = new List<Employee>() 
        { 
              new Employee 
            { 
               sID = 100, 
               Name = "ASHOK" 
            }, 
            new Employee 
            {
               sID = 101, 
               Name = "SHAKTHI" 
            }, 
            new Employee 
            { 
               sID = 102, 
               Name = "RAVI" 
            }, 
            new Employee
            {
               sID=100,
               Name="ashok"
            } 
        };
        var lstEmployeeDetails = lstEmployee.Distinct(new EmployeeComparer());
   }  
    public class Employee
    {
       public int sID { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; } 
       public override bool Equals(object obj)
       {
         return this.sID == ((Employee)obj).sID && this.Name == 
         ((Employee)obj).Name;
       }
       public override int GetHashCode()
       {
         return this.sID.GetHashCode() ^ this.Name.GetHashCode();
       }
    }    


    public class EmployeeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
    { 
       public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
       { 
          return x.sID == y.sID && x.Name == y.Name;
        }
        public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
        { 
          return obj.sID.GetHashCode()^ obj.Name.GetHashCode(); 
        }
    }
```

in the list duplicate data there for sid=101 couple of time(duplicate)with small case. I have to get only "ASHOK" and id=101

Comment: did you less put some code? because it look like some code is missing and you're using distinct it mean you have not repeat item in your list share your output list.

Comment: Ouput: ASHOK,SHAKTHI,RAVI,ashok.
Expected out put is:ASHOK,SHAKTHI,RAVI

Comment: distinct is not working because case in sensitive so I override equals method to get irrespective of casesensitive  it should validate and should display disnct names

Comment: you can paste your code here https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: here is the link[https://dotnetfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=8rJHbp6dKf]